# How can I disable right click event on ajaxfallbacklink in Wicket framework?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, wicket, right-click

How can I disable right click event on ajaxfallbacklink in Wicket framework (6)?
If using ajaxfallbacklink, and opening a new tab (as rightclick on mouse would let me do), i will get an exception.

(http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/AjaxFallbackLink.html)
" ajax target if this linked was invoked using ajax, null otherwise"

Therefore I would like to disable the rightclickbrowser menu, or fix the exception for these kinds of links. How could I do this in a good way codewise?

Comment: Do you check if target parameter is null? It will be null if it's a non-ajax call. Only call target.add() if target is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christophs answer got me on the right track. Which is "Before opening a new tab/win with an ajaxlink (rightclick), check that target itself (and maybe it's parameter) is not null and take precautions for that. setResponsePage(YOURPAGE) or something". Doh;) Chr. should have the credits for this.